# Stripe two subscriptions one checkout?

Tags: stripe-payments, payment-gateway, checkout

The billing of my subscriptions require anual and monthly payments.
As it isn't possible within stripe to create one subscription containing a monthly and a yearly billed price, I'd like to ask how it could be possible to realise this workflow anyways?

Could it be possible to add 2 subscriptions (one monthly and the other yearly billed) to one checkout session?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The yearly billed payment is based on a fixed price and the payment that should be charged monthly is a usage based price per 10 units.

Answer (score 0):

With Checkout, the [line items](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-line_items) must have the same billing interval so having a monthly and a yearly interval subscriptions on one checkout session is not a possibility. The alternative is to create two separate checkout sessions for products with different billing intervals.